# Which framework do I need to import for using NSOpenPanel class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to Open File Dialog in my application to upload a particular selected file onto the server in Objective-C. I am using the following code in my application, but it seems to give an error while creating an object of NSOpenPanel.

Please help me out.

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
openPanel.title = @"Choose a .TXT file";
openPanel.showsResizeIndicator = YES;
openPanel.showsHiddenFiles = NO;
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = NO;
openPanel.canCreateDirectories = YES;
openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
openPanel.allowedFileTypes = @[@"txt", @"jpg", @"jpeg", @"zip", @"png"];

[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:appDelegate.controlsWindow
                  completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {

      if (result==NSOKButton) {

          NSURL *selection = openPanel.URLs[0];
          NSString* path = [selection.path stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath];

          //do something with the file at "path"

      }

  }];
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post to show the error message that you're having. Also, are you using `NSOpenPanel` for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

NSOpenPanel doesn't exist on iOS. The whole concept of files is pretty well hidden from users in most cases. What's the end goal here? What kind of "files" do you want to upload to a server?

UIKit has the [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/), which you can use to select images from the Photo Library, for instance.

Comment: I also wants to pick any ".txt", ".pdf", ".doc" files from iPhone